# Remove "0%" labels from a plotly pie chart in Python

Tags: python, plotly

I need to plot a pie chart that shows all descriptions in a legend, despite the values being zero. However, I would like also to remove the "0%"s labels from the chart. An example:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know anything about plotly so am not going to post an answer, but it looks like you can control whether text is hidden or shown with an overflow. See the docs: https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/#controlling-text-fontsize-with-uniformtext

Comment: Yes, you're right, the solution was there. I force to put the labels inside the slices and then it worked using  uniformtext_minsize=12, uniformtext_mode='hide'.

Comment: Feel free to submit an answer, you're allowed to answer your own questions. Make it good and you'll get points.

Answer (score 2):

I could fix a limit to the labels using two parameters: uniformtext_minsize and uniformtext_mode:

```
    fig.update_traces(textposition='inside')
    fig.update_layout(
    height=400,
    width=430,
    uniformtext_minsize=10, uniformtext_mode='hide',
    legend=dict(font=dict(size=12)),
    margin=dict(
        l=0,
        r=0,
        b=0,
        t=50,
        pad=0
    )
```

As Plotly adjusts the font size to fit labels inside pie slices, those parameters hide the label if it was impossible to show it inside the slice using uniformtext_minsize font size, as it can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: this did not work for me

Comment: I checked the site (I'm not working there anymore) and it still working there. Maybe you should play around with the font size parameter.